# Fullcalendar and jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar v2.7.1  and jQuery datepicker.  After selecting a month/year from the datepicker, how do you advance the fullcalendar to the values selected from the datepicker?

The older version of fullcalendar v1.5.4 use to work using the code below.

**jQuery**

```
('#datepicker').datepicker({  
  onChangeMonthYear: function(month, year, inst) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate',month, year, inst);
  },  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

according to the Documentation [gotoDate](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/gotoDate/) accepts a [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) object.

So, try with this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar();
$('#datepicker').datepicker({  
  onChangeMonthYear: function(y, m, inst) {
        var day = moment({ year :y, month :m });
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate',day);
  },  
});
```

See this working example: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tyjp20c3/)